# checking the value in a table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

let me I have a table called to test and another table called testTwo testTwo.

I got a value (row) from the table test which is rollNo. Now Ii want to check and compare that if there is any row called rollNo rollNo exists in my testTwo testTwo table.

How can Ii do this in asp.net? Thanks.

I am adding some sample code here to get the concept that what Ii am trying to do.

what can be the way that Ii can compare my existing value with the existing table that the testTwo the tabletable has the row ( rollNO)

Answer (score 0):

If your second table is DataTable, you can write something like below.

```
DataTable table=testTwo;//table example

DataColumnCollection columns = table.Columns;        
if (columns.Contains("rollNO"))
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: let me try this.